# Gunicorn is failing to start with code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, gunicorn

Gunicorn works when testing with 0.0.0.0:8000 but failing with the production version below.
Tried switching user:group to myproject:myproject, root:nginx, myproject:nginx nothing working

sudo systemctl status gunicorn

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-08-30 08:49:57 PDT; 5s ago
    Process: 5576 ExecStart=/var/www/myproject/public_py/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/myproject/public_py/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
    Main PID: 5576 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 30 08:49:57 myprojecthost systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 30 08:49:57 myprojecthost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 30 08:49:57 myprojecthost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myproject/public_py
ExecStart=/var/www/myproject/public_py/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/myproject/public_py/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Project lives in `/var/www/myproject`

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[crit] 1198#0: *51 connect() to unix:/var/www/myproject/public_py/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: myproject.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/myproject/public_py/myproject.sock:/", host: "myproject.com"
```

stat /var/www/myproject/public_py/env/bin/gunicorn

```
  File: /var/www/myproject/public_py/env/bin/gunicorn
  Size: 243         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 1066021     Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  984/   nginx)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Access: 2020-08-30 08:07:44.939754370 -0700
Modify: 2020-08-29 18:16:27.280494281 -0700
Change: 2020-08-30 08:46:09.047708570 -0700
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

nginx was being blocked via SElinux, to resolve change to permissive.